# Ensure that we do not have to rewrite React code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was learning React and JS and came across some videos saying that after they have created their products, they faced the situations that they had to rewrite their code since it was quite difficult to add new features and make changes easily. Then I tried to find some articles explaining how to write maintainable code IN ADVANCE so that we do not have to rewrite it later. But basically the majority of articles say that destructuring or propTypes is the way to go. But I wonder if there are MAIN and IMPORTANT advice we have to keep in mind before start writing code for our product so we do not have to rewrite in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips to have a scalable React code:

1. Use "inversion of control" pattern
   This means you must develop agnostic components, without any state or logic. All the logic shall be handled by a controller (the main parent). For example, a button would look like this:

```js
interface ButtonProps {
variant?: "primary" | "secondary";
onClick?: ()=> void;
disabled?:false;
icon?: Icon;
text: string;
}

export default function Button ({variant="primary", onClick, disabled=false, icon, text}:ButtonProps){
  return (
    <Root variant={variant} onClick={onClick} disabled={disabled}>
        {icon && <Icon icon={icon}/>
        {text}
    </Root>
    )
}
```

Separation of concern is very important.

This way, you can reuse this button everywhere in a lot of different scenarios without changing its code or logic. A component should do nothing but receive orders. The logic is only handled by controllers.

2. Use render props

Sometimes, you may want different renderings for a component, and end up adding more and more props to cover upcoming usecases. The code may quickly become muddy. So don't hesitate to use render props. Let's take the example of a tooltip:

```js
function Tooltip ({content, disabled, children}){
  return (
  disabled ? children :
    <Root>
      <Content>
        {content}
      </Content>
    {children}
   </Root>
  )
  }

const Parent = ({data}) => {
const getTooltip = ({data}) => <>{data.color} - {data.percentage}</>
      return (
        {data.map((d,i)=> (
        <Tooltip content={getTooltip(d)} disabled={!!d.username}/>
            {d.username}
        </Tooltip>
    ))}
  )
}
```

3. Keep your props name as clear and agnostic as possible
4. Use Typescript

Once the codebase becomes larger and larger, it remains easy to know what prop to send to each component, and you never do any mistake that may crash the app.

5. Test all your functions.
   And run the tests before each commit.

Comment: hey : ) thank you for your comments sorry just some questions. Firstly, you advised to use "inversion of control, are there any more useful patterns for React I should check out? Secondly, in terms of reusability, I saw some devs instead of creating ajax requests in useEffect, they just use custom hooks to achieve reusability to send ajax requests. Is that viable? Thirdly, as you know to use redux in react we use connect() for certain components. But connect() makes component not reusable thus devs do not use connect in any component and just try to achieve reusability.

Comment: have you heard or seen anything about the last point?

Comment: Inversion of control, separation of concerns, agnosticity, dry code and kiss (keep it simple & stupid) are the patterns you should follow. I advise you to handle all api call in separate files, and then import these functions where you need them. You don't need redux (or use redux hooks useSelector and useDispatch, not connect). React Context does the job. Just keep only a few paramount informations in this context and don't update it all the time. Props are fine if your app architecture is well designed. Huge redux store are stupid imho. Jotai seems great too to handle global states.

Comment: For testing, first write your tests in Jest (what usecases should the function cover?). Otherwise, you may try to make the test fit to your function instead of making your function fit to the test. It's called TTD: test driven development. Also, develop your components in Storybook.

Comment: you mean by "I advise you to handle all api call in separate files", there is no need to create custom hook as, for example, useHttp? Lastly, concerning create-react-app, I have seen cases when devs do not use CRA and create their own template from scratch and the reason is that it gets easier to make changes to webpack.config file and package,json will contain only packages that we need. Do you support this? or is it best to still use CRA and use npm run eject? Just very briefly : )

Comment: Create your own hook is useful because you can use React's hook inside (useMemo, useCallback, etc.). If you don't need them, it's purely a fancy name (but perfectly fine. Just keep a consistant naming policy). CRA is ok for small projects, but not for pro applications. You need to control your bundle size. Also, you can do many things with a custom webpack such as aliases (no more ../../components/button, just @components/button for ex).

Comment: by "You need to control your bundle size" you mean by default CRA installs a lot of packages that we might NOT need but with custom template we only have what we need. Is that the main reason? : ). Sorry dude this is my latest question, you know, I just love this stuff )). It is about SOLID in React. Which of these principles are mostly applicable to React or which do you use? Yeah I know single responsibility is very important but how about the others. Again very very briefly. Thank you dude I owe you )))

Comment: Yeah, with a custom webpack file you be able to only have the necessary packages, to compress the chunks the way you want, etc. I You can use all SOLID's principles. Just adapt them to your vision and your app. No problem, if you feel like you owe me one then you can check out my album when it's out lol (I'll put the name here when the time comes haha). Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 1):

At work, we only have to rewrite code because our client change his mind often. Depending on your context, you might have no choice but to rewrite part of your code but if it's about a personal project, well just think about the feature you want to implement, but also what you **might** want to implement in the future, and try to create as much generic code as you can. Reusability is something I don't see often and it sadden me a lot.

You might want to do a functional (and then technical) conception and split it into User Stories (scenario) to better understand what you need and which functionality you could merge. Avoid big ass components if you can.

All this work is supposed to help you build a solid base for you application so in case you have to evolve a functionality, well you will focus on that and avoid side effects.